# Varying cloudinary images in a django template

Tags: html, django, cloudinary

I'm trying to vary images based on a variable - id in the Django template.

```
<img href="'https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/'|add:{{ object.id }}|add:'.png'" class="mx-auto" width="100px" alt="No Image"/>
```

object.id is passed into the template from a Queryset object (i.e. object).

Page load, but image does not show up and goes to alt="No Image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `|add:` etc are *not* interpreted by the Django template engine, since these are not between curly brackets (`{{ … }}`), nor templat tag brackets (`{% … %}`). THis is also not necessary, you can create the URL with:

```
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/{{ object.id }}.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't work for me. The images are not getting pulled from Cloudinary.

Comment: @user10421193: are you sure the URI is correct, I find the  `/.../` part very "weird".

Comment: Awesome thanks you were right - it's "src" not "href"